# Vectorization vs SIMD vs Workshare in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp, vectorization

From your experience, which code snippet is the fastest?

Vectorization

```
x(2:ndof - 1) = x(2:ndof - 1) - dt*( &
    x(ndof + 1:ndof+ ndof - 2) + (ndof + 3:ndof + ndof))
```

Vectorization + workshare

```
!$omp parallel workshare schedule (runtime)
    x(2:ndof - 1) = x(2:ndof - 1) - dt*( &
    x(ndof + 1:ndof+ ndof - 2) + (ndof + 3:ndof + ndof))
!$omp end parallel workshare
```

Explicit loop + single instruction multiple data of openmp

```
!$omp parallel do simd schedule (runtime)
    do idx = 2, ndof - 1, 1
        x(idx) = x(idx) - (dt*coef*( &
            x(ndof+idx - 1) + x(ndof + idx+1)))
    end do
!$omp end parallel do simd
```

I do not include a simple explicit loop as it is the one I want to improve performance.

Comment: It will depend at the very least on the hardware you are using, compiler and the version of the compiler, and could easily change if you change any one of those. The length of the loop is probably important as well, as is how the variables you are using is declared. The only way to find out is to benchmark the case you are interested in on the hardware in using the compiler you are interested in

Comment: Without knowing the number of threads and types of cores you are using even knowing the compiler version and the compiler flags won't help. You should do some testing first. If you are optimizing some existing software, you have to test and test and test. The size of the problem could easilly change the outcome.

Comment: @Ian Bush and @Vladimir so no easy way for it `:-D`. I was feeling a little bit overwhelmed by it but the parameters you are pointing out make sense.

Comment: In the example, if you enable diagnostics, the compiler should tell you the loop isn't simd vectorizable.  You would need an assertion such as omp simd safelen(8) (in effect, asserting ndof > 8). Successful vectorization of array assignments might require implicit generation of a copy, which the compiler may decide to forgo, as it doubles the memory traffic, and might lead to cache thrashing. For auto-vectorization where an assertion is not needed, there may be no difference in performance between array assignment, for simd, and a plain loop, if suitable compiler flags may be passed.